# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot update. Database or object is read-only

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ms-access

I am using Spring 3.1.2 and Hibernate 4.1.5_SP1.  I am trying to import CSV files into dynamically created Access files.  The code looks similar to this:

```
    final SingleConnectionDataSource ds = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
    ds.setUrl(myBean.getMicrosoftAccessDriverUrl() + file.getAbsolutePath());
    final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    final String strSQL = "SELECT * INTO " + accessTableName + " FROM 
         [Text;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" + csvFile.getPath()+ ";].[" + 
         csvFile.getName() + "]";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(strSQL);
    ds.getConnection().close();
```

Which generates an error like:

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad 
 SQL grammar 
  [SELECT * INTO myTable 
  FROM [Text;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\somePath;].[myAccessFile.accdb]]; 
 nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft 
 Access Driver]  Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.
```

My Datasource URL is similar to:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\somePath\myAccessFile.accdb
```

I checked the files and they are NOT read-only.  Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got the `strSQL` value and tried to run it in your SQL Server?

Comment: If your access database is opened by another session, you can't update. Close Access database sessions.

Comment: I checked pretty thoroughly and I don't see it being opened anywhere else. I close it after the statement has executed

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have SQL Server installed to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FROM` clause does not look correct to me.

```
SELECT * INTO myTable 
FROM [Text;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\somePath;].[myAccessFile.accdb]
```

I thought you intended to import from CSV into an Access table.  If so, I think you should be using the CSV file name in place of the Access file (`myAccessFile.accdb`).

```
SELECT * INTO myTable 
FROM [Text;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\somePath;].[YourFile.csv]
```

Comment: Hmm, my real code does show csv file, but my logging shows the access file output.  I will double-check what's going on there.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  My FileFilter broke in earlier code and was incorrectly sending the access file to the csv import function instead of the csv file.